# pinning and core affinity with openblas on AMD Epyc cpu

Tags: pinning, openblas

I am using openblas on the AMD Epyc 'zen' cpus. To install it I simply did  make TARGET=ZEN

I have a system with 2x 7601 (i.e. 2 x32 cores) and I can run across all cores and get an ok GFLOPS number from DGEMM using export OMP_NUM_THREADS=64

But I am now trying to pin it to a smaller set of cores, just 2 cores, with 1 core on 1 socket and the second core on the other socket. So I set

1)
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 32"
but it always dumps the 2 threads on to the first 2 cores.

2) I have logged out, logged back in and tried
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
numactl -C 0,31 ./mt-dgemm
but again it dumps them onto cores 0 and 1

3) I have logged out, logged back in and tried
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
taskset-c 0,31 ./mt-dgemm
but again it dumps them onto cores 0 and 1

But if I try just a single core, OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 and then do a taskset or numactl and change the core ID to 4 or 8 or 52 or whatever it then successfully pins that single thread to the core that I requested it to.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong when I try to pin 2 or more cores to specific CPU ids?

Many thanks!

(I am using CentOS 7.4 with GCC 7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, when building openblas use the NO_AFFINITY=1 flag to disable the automatic affinity witnessed above. Thus;

```
make TARGET=zen NO_AFFINITY=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following commands, do they work for you? 
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
numactl --physcpubind=0,31 ./mt-dgemm

Comment: No, I am afraid that just sticks them on CPUid 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

Thread placement can be controlled using openMP environment variables: OMP_PLACES & OMP_PROC_BIND
For example:

> > **OMP_PLACES="{0}" OMP_PROC_BIND=spread OMP_NUM_THREADS=64  ./mt-dgemm** 
> >     This will schedule all 64 threads to core 0.

You can get further info from below link:
http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-affinity.html